# Invalid use of group function but there is no GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to run this query:

```
UPDATE `ps_category_lang` cl 
  LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop p 
    ON cl.id_category=p.id_category_default 
     AND cl.id_shop=p.id_shop 
     AND p.available_for_order =1 
     AND p.visibility != 'none' 
  LEFT JOIN ps_specific_price sp 
    ON p.id_product=sp.id_product 
    AND ((sp.`from` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() >= sp.`from`) 
    AND (sp.`to` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() <= sp.`to`)) 
    AND (sp.id_shop=0 OR sp.id_shop=p.id_shop)
  SET cl.meta_title=CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      TRIM(cl.`meta_title`),
      'från', 
      1
    ), 
    'från ', 
    FORMAT(
      ROUND(
        min(p.price-IF(sp.reduction>0,sp.reduction, 0)
      ) * 
      (SELECT conversion_rate 
         FROM ps_currency 
         WHERE iso_code='SEK' 
           AND deleted=0
      )
    ),
    0, 
   'sv_SE'),
   ' kr.',
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(cl.`meta_title`, ' kr.', -1)
   )
   WHERE cl.`id_lang` = 7 
     AND cl.meta_title LIKE '% från%' 
     AND cl.meta_title LIKE '% kr.%' 
     AND p.available_for_order= 1
```

but it gives the error ' #1111 - Invalid use of group function ', although there is no group by. Why is it giving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aggregate functions directly in an `UPDATE` query - and any query that uses an aggregate function (such as `min`, in yours) gets an implicit `group by` added.

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY
>   clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows

[manual ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html)

And to pare it down to  simple example:

`update the_table set value = min(value)`

will generate your `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.

To accomplish the intent of that query, you would need to do it this way:

`update the_table set value = (select min(value) from the_table)`

This means that the source of your error is this particular part of the query, `min(p.price-IF(sp.reduction>0,sp.reduction, 0)`, and that in order to fix it, you would need to convert that to a subquery that calculates the value for you.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create this field for the value, or is it a temporary value, since there is no such field in the table. I am having hard time here trying to put the 'update the_table set value = (select min(value) from the_table) ' into the right place. Would you mind inserting it in the right way? Would be very grateful.

Comment: sorry my answer was just a general solution - can you explain why you are using `min(p.price ...` in the first place?

Comment: I solved it by using temporary table. The purpose of this query is update the shop category meta titles, so the visitor can see right away the lowest price in the selected category.
Thank you very much, I wouldn't have any idea where to look before you pointed it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using temp tables like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT id_category_default, MIN(p.price-IF(sp.reduction>0,sp.reduction, 0)) AS minprice FROM ps_product_shop p LEFT JOIN ps_specific_price sp ON p.id_product=sp.id_product AND ((sp.`from` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() >= sp.`from`) AND (sp.`to` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() <= sp.`to`)) AND (sp.id_shop=0 OR sp.id_shop=p.id_shop) WHERE p.available_for_order= 1 GROUP BY p.id_category_default;
UPDATE `ps_category_lang` cl LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop p ON cl.id_category=p.id_category_default AND cl.id_shop=p.id_shop AND p.available_for_order =1 AND p.visibility != 'none' LEFT JOIN ps_specific_price sp ON p.id_product=sp.id_product AND ((sp.`from` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() >= sp.`from`) AND (sp.`to` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR NOW() <= sp.`to`)) AND (sp.id_shop=0 OR sp.id_shop=p.id_shop) LEFT JOIN tmp t on t.id_category_default=p.id_category_default AND t.minprice is not null
SET cl.meta_title=CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(cl.`meta_title`),'från', 1), 'från ',FORMAT(ROUND(t.minprice)*(SELECT conversion_rate FROM ps_currency WHERE iso_code='SEK' AND deleted=0),0, 'sv_SE'),' kr.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(cl.`meta_title`, ' kr.', -1))
WHERE cl.`id_lang` = 7 AND cl.meta_title LIKE '% från%' AND cl.meta_title LIKE '% kr.%' AND p.available_for_order= 1 ;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
```

Comment: You could have put that subquery directly into the main query, instead of the temp table. You may also consider just making it a view.so its always available